# Proper Way to Create Compound Index on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to improve the results on an expensive mysql search. I Have a query in Python that looks like the following:

```
query = ("SELECT s.* "
         "FROM stores_standardized ss "
         "LEFT JOIN stores s "
         "ON s.storeID = ss.store_ID "
         "WHERE s.phone = %s "
         "OR (ss.fulladdress = %s "
         "AND ss.city = %s "
         "AND ss.state = %s "
         "AND ss.zip = %s "
         "AND ss.country = %s "
         "AND ss.number = %s "
         "AND ss.street = %s "
         "AND ss.type = %s) "              
         "AND ss.standardizedname = %s"
     )
```

I know that I need an index, but I'm confused as to where I should start my index. Which of the following (or something else), would be the best index?

Option 1:

```
create index idx 
on stores_standardized
(fulladdress,city,state,zip,country,number,street,type,standardizedname);
```

and then have a separate index for store_ID on stores_standardized. Or is it better to have them all combined:

Option 2:

```
create index idx 
on stores_standardized
(store_ID,fulladdress,city,state,zip,country,number,street,type,standardizedname);
```

**Edit**
Running explain provides the following:

```
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys       | key     | key_len | ref                        | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | ss    | index  | name,search,search2 | search2 | 864     | NULL                       | 1803772 | Using index |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | s     | eq_ref | PRIMARY             | PRIMARY | 8       | dbname.ss.store_ID         |       1 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: Please provide the EXPLAIN for the above (although I always find LEFT JOIN with an OR on 2 different tables very confusing)

Comment: You can check via explain which is used preferred by mysql.

Comment: I've provided the explain results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, I believe the only indexes that can help this query are on the `store_ID` field of each table; the `OR` in your `WHERE` conditions will pretty much eliminate the use of indices there; also, your `X OR (Y) AND Z` condition is slightly ambiguous to look at.

Your best bet for performance increases is to separate it out into separate similar queries (each with one part of the `OR`) and UNION those queries together. The UNION will eliminate any duplicate results, and you can then take advantage separate indices for each part; one with an index on `phone` and another on (some of) the list of field with `AND`ed conditions; which fields would be best will vary based on your expected data distribution.

Comment: Wow, this worked amazing! How come the "OR" statement breaks indexing?

Comment: MySQL just plain can't use indexes in those cases. **Maybe** in an `X AND (Y OR Z)` situation, but I am not that versed with the intricacies of that issue.